# Does interactivity affect training performance?

Tags: slideshow, end-user-training

My office has recently created a bunch of computer based trainings (CBTs). They're basically slides with audio. Some of them automatically advance to the next slide and others require a manual click for each slide. Does the degree of interactivity with such a presentation have any effect, positive or negative, on how well the user retains information and thus performs on the evaluation?

Comment: Some scientists wouldn't say that manually clicking through the slides is interactive at all. It's navigating and not interacting. http://www.zhw.uni-hamburg.de/pdfs/Interactivity.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the goal of a training is to engage the trainee. This could be done through interactivity, but please avoid making interactivity the goal. Often we talk about such effects in UX and psychology, but a perfectly designed interaction pattern can never compensate for bad quality content.

Some talks (pure video, for example, TED talks / Coursera) can be much more engaging than interactive training material.

Strictly answering your question: interactivity can be a good way of engaging your audience, for educational purposes. Asking them questions (even without expecting answers) will already prime them. Forcing your users to press a button to advance to the next slide may have an effect, though I doubt it is significant.

I think a stronger reason to switch to manually advancing through the slides, is that auto-advancing takes away user-control and might interfere with the training itself: perhaps the trainee did not yet finish reading/understanding the current slide?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Interactivity is critical for learning repetition and re-enforcement. ARS (Automated Response Systems) such as the multiple choice clickers used in universities, continuing medical education, etc... improve learning. Also take a look at [Kahn Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/)

They demonstrate very well across their learning paths, and activities how interactivity enhances the learning experience.

Another great example is the Redis (nosql db system) tutorial interface:

[Redis Tutorial](http://try.redis.io/)